# Sources for Benchmarks of Prices in the Star Wars Universe

Tags: lore, system-agnostic, equipment, economy, star-wars

I am planning to run a Star Wars campaign, and I would like to get a better feel for the setting's economical 'realities', such as *approximate* relative prices of things and services. I understand that that there are fluctuations of such things (though a combination of a handwavy setting and the ease of interstellar trade seem to equalise prices more across the galaxy), so I'm not trying to get it right to the last decicredit - orders of magnitude would suffice. Typical items an adventurer would need, typical services like interstellar flight tickets, expenses for hyperflights and ship maintenance - that sort of thing.

What would be a good (best) source which has a lot of such prices or price comparisons in one book, list or other form of compiled material (i.e. not a myriad of scattered pages)? Doesn't matter which of the systems it's made for, so long as it presents a relatively comprehensive and mostly-coherent picture of comparative worth of various things and services. Old Republic era is preferred, but I think that's less likely to be available, and if it's not, I think I should be able to get by almost as well with Rebellion era.

Comment: With the fluctuating economies across regions, worlds, and time, this seems too broad.

Comment: Reopened. This is a question about a genuine tabletop RPG setting. If folks can ask about the Forgotten Realms in the scope of RPG play (but no specific RPG), they can do the same about The Galaxy Far, Far Away. RPG players will give a better, different, or more specific answer about TGFFA issues because they will be context-aware as to this information's functional purpose, as opposed to it merely being trivia.

Comment: I still think this is too broad for the reasons in my first comment.

Comment: Can you specify which system you're using?

Comment: @ObliviousSage I can, but I shouldn't, because it could only ever serve to confuse people about the scope of the question, which is about the lore (economics), not about the system crunch. Already we have [one of the answers](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/166140) which seems to treat this as a 'how to crunch' question; I would rather not increase the probability of people arriving at such misconceptions.

Comment: I guess I'm wondering what you want this information *for* if not for setting prices paid by PCs in your game, which presumably uses some game system. Failing to specify a system makes this feel a lot like a [campaign research question](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1604/3548).

Answer (score 5):

### No such source material exists.

To the extent of what you're asking for, at least. You're not going to find any material out there that details the difference of prices between a crate of E-11s on Duros vs. Ord Mantel. I would suspect across all material out there, it is almost certainly wildly inconsistent.

### That said, most of the SW rpg systems have been excellent and contain lists of goods for you to compare values of.

I personally would recommend the current FFG system for Star Wars, Edge of the Empire/Age of Rebellion/Force and Destiny. The system contains a vast amount of items, and the costs are at least a place to start.

Sadly, travel costs between systems is lacking in the books, but I do believe EotE contains a listing for cargo costs of generic goods.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't plan on making acquisition of riches an important part of your campaign and thus can live with a simplified player economy, here is a system I cobbled together:

Both prices and wealth are only tracked on a exponential scale as orders of magnitude (With steps of 1$, 10$, 100$, 1000$, 10.000$ and 100.000$ in my case, but for a galactic economy, you might want to push the scale higher), where the value that is associated with a certain level of wealth is equal to the kind of purchase that you mull over a lot when offered, because it might drag down your budget.

For example, take a middle class household. For them, a holiday in Australia would probably be considered borderline -- they might afford it once, but certainly not every year. The money needed for that is several thousand per person, thus, we can define that middle class household to correspond to the wealth of 1000$, because that's the kind of purchase that is borderline for them.

If somebody buys something with a price below their wealth level, their wealth doesn't go down (unless it's a bulk purchase of sufficient magnitude to bump it up some levels). Buying a meal (1$-level unless you're going to a fancy restaurant) doesn't affect how rich somebody is, usually, and this way we don't need bookkeeping over those tiny purchases.

If somebody buys something of the same price as their wealth level (e.g. the flight to Australia mentioned above), they roll a die and have a chance to drop one level in wealth (I set that chance to 30%, so you can make about three purchases of your wealth level before you're broke).

If somebody buys above their wealth level, they drop one level automatically, and still have to roll the die for possibly a second drop. For each further level above their own, that wealth loss doubles. If that wealth loss exceeds their ability to drop (You can't drop below 1$ wealth), then the purchase just doesn't happen.

The assumption here is that what this drop in wealth represents can be many things. Maybe you had to just access your savings account and now it's empty and you need to save again before being able to spend big. Maybe you took out a loan. Maybe you sold some property to afford it, and now need to save to buy that again.

To move up in wealth level, a character needs to get a profit of a level above their own (so for example a 10.000$ profit for the 1000$ middle class household), and then gets to roll a die to move up (I set the chance to go down with wealth level, by requiring a roll under 4 on a D4 to D12 depending on level, but you can change that if you consider that a depressing model of social mobility). Profits two or more levels above their wealth means one automatic step up the scale.

This system allows me to very easily make up the prices of things when the players want to buy, by using one of the following heuristics:

1. Do I consider that purchase and the possible threat of poverty for the heroes to be interesting in terms of plot? If not, then it's somewhere below their wealth level and can be ignored.
2. Where would I put the Earth equivalent in terms of price category? A personal spaceship in Star Wars seems to be rarer than having a car on Earth, so since a car is a high-end middle-class purchase (Meaning I'd peg it as 1000$ for a used car and 10.000$ for a new one), a spaceship is probably a 10.000$ purchase, or 100.000$ if you want a luxury one.
3. How rich is the person making it? This one works better in a pre-industrial setting, but still: Since wealth is tied to income, and income gained by selling things, you can in return determine the price of things from the wealth of its maker, or in case of services, from the service provider. So a slave, being poor, is probably not going to be expensive, but hiring a renowned bounty hunter, who own their own ship, should probably costs in that same range as the spaceship.

Comment: Is this kind of a frame challenge in that OP doesn't need a specific SW-based economy? Your idea seems more like a general approach to economy rather than one modeled after the SW universe.

Comment: I'm drowning in advice on abstracted price categories, but I'm already familiar with such approaches. I'm seeking the benchmarks specifically to be able to *apply* such categorisation in actual practice.